# Download thousands of images with Asyncio and Aiohttp

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp, timeoutexception

I've been trying to download thousands of images in my local filesystem but it hasn't worked correctly because I got an exception called **asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError** when I had downloaded around 5,000 images separated by directories.

The first time I executed next script I got 16.000 downloads, but each time I execute it, it decrease the number of downloaded images and currently I'm around 5,000 images.

That's the script I've implemented:

```py
import os
import asyncio
import aiofiles
import async_timeout

from aiohttp import ClientSession
from generator import generate_hash
from logger import logger
from typing import List, Dict, Any

async def download_file(session: Any, remote_url: str, filename: str) -> None:
    try:
        async with async_timeout.timeout(120):
            async with session.get(remote_url) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    async with aiofiles.open(filename, mode='wb') as f:
                        async for data in response.content.iter_chunked(1024):
                            await f.write(data)
                else:
                    logger.error(f"Error to get {filename} from Remote Server")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        logger.error(f"Timeout error to download {filename} into Local Server")
        raise
    
async def download_files(images: List[Dict[str, Any]], path: str) -> None:
    headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"}
    async with ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(download_file(session, image['resource'], get_filename(image, path))) for image in images]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        
def download_images(images: List[Dict[str, Any]], path: str) -> None:
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(download_files(images, path))
        loop.run_until_complete(future)
        logger.info(f'Images from Remote Server have been downloaded successfully')
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error(f'Error to download images from Remote Server: {error}')
        raise

def get_filename(image: Dict[str, Any], path: str) -> str:
    image_dir = '{}/{}'.format(path, image['id'])
    image_file = '{}.jpg'.format(generate_hash(image['resource']))
    if not os.path.exists(image_dir):
        os.makedirs(image_dir)
    return os.path.join(image_dir, image_file)


def main():
    images = [
                 {
                     'id': '10755431', 
                     'resource': 'http://image1.jpg'
                 }, 
                 {
                     'id': '10755432',
                     'resource': 'http://image2.jpg'
                 }, 
                 {
                     'id': '101426201',
                     'recurso': 'http://image3.jpg'
                 }
             ]
    IMAGES_PATH = '/home/stivenramireza'
    download_images(images, IMAGES_PATH)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I got this error:

```py
ERROR:root:Timeout error to download /home/stivenramireza/10755431/664e3bdd10cd69452774f38ec822a9eb.jpg into Local Server
ERROR:root:Error to download images from Remote Server: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stivenramireza/storage/main.py", line 17, in download_file
    async for data in response.content.iter_chunked(1024):
  File "/home/stivenramireza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 39, in __anext__
    rv = await self.read_func()
  File "/home/stivenramireza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 368, in read
    await self._wait('read')
  File "/home/stivenramireza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 296, in _wait
    await waiter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 67, in main
    download_images(images, IMAGES_PATH)
  File "/home/stivenramireza/storage/main.py", line 34, in download_images
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/stivenramireza/storage/main.py", line 28, in download_files
    await asyncio.gather(*[asyncio.ensure_future(download_file(session, image['recurso'], get_filename(image, path))) for image in images])
  File "/home/stivenramireza/storage/main.py", line 20, in download_file
    logger.error(f"Error to get {filename} from Re Server")
  File "/home/stivenramireza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/async_timeout/__init__.py", line 55, in __aexit__
    self._do_exit(exc_type)
  File "/home/stivenramireza/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/async_timeout/__init__.py", line 92, in _do_exit
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `download_file` function catches the timeout error **and re-raises it**. Your `download_files` function uses `asyncio.gather()` which exits on first exception and propagates it to the caller. It is reasonable to assume that, when downloading a large number of files, sooner or later one of them times out, in which case your whole program gets interrupted.

> What should I do?

That depends on what you *want* your program to do in case of a timeout. For example, you might want to retry that file, or you might want to give up. But you most likely don't want to interrupt the whole download because of a single file that has timed out.

While re-raising an exception you've caught is in many cases the right thing to do, it is not the right thing here. You can change `raise` at the end of `download_file` to `return (remote_url, filename)` which will result in `gather()` returning a list of failed downloads and you can try to download them again.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342! I'll do that.